How to use overload from the typing package within a higher-order function in Python?
Returning an overloaded function from a higher-order callable does not produce expected results with respect to type hints: namely, the resulting function behaves as if it was unannotated at all.
Here a minimal example:
from typing import Optional, overload


def get_f(b: int):
    @overload
    def f(x: int) -> str: ...

    @overload
    def f(x: int, c: bool) -> int: ...

    def f(x: int, c: Optional[bool] = None) -> int | str:
        return 2 * x * b if c is not None else "s"

    return f


d = get_f(2)
a = d(2)
b = a ** 2

Here mypy does not realize that b = a**2 leads to an TypeError. How to remedy this?

Do other type checking packages detect this? It might just be a limitation of mypy.

@Barmar it's not a limitation, it's explicit PEP484 conformance. get_f does not specify the return type, so it defaults to Any. And you can do whatever you want with Any (check with reveal_type(d)).

@STerliakov Even though I prefer explicit return annotations, pyright is and will remain non-conformant with this specification about requiring return type annotations, and it seems like it's a popular request on mypy. I wouldn't be surprised if that PEP 484 specification was made obsolete in the future.

@dROOOze I have weird deja vu feeling that we have already discussed that... Yep, Pyright is, but OP asks about mypy and I'm in the camp of people supporting decision to insist on Any default instead of typescript-like inference that tends to bite you at some other end of the codebase in a few months:)

You can create a type denoting an overloaded callable using typing.Protocol (read the PEP to learn more about structural subtyping):
from typing import Optional, Protocol, overload


class FProtocol(Protocol):
    @overload
    def __call__(self, x: int) -> str: ...
    @overload
    def __call__(self, x: int, c: bool) -> int: ...
    

def get_f(b: int) -> FProtocol:
    @overload
    def f(x: int) -> str: ...

    @overload
    def f(x: int, c: bool) -> int: ...

    def f(x: int, c: Optional[bool] = None) -> int | str:
        return 2 * x * b if c is not None else "s"

    return f


d = get_f(2)
a = d(2)
b = a ** 2  # E: Unsupported operand types for ** ("str" and "int")  [operator]

mypy playground pyright playground
Using protocol is the only way to specify an overloaded callable, as far as I know.
When you leave the return type unspecified, it defaults to Any, as PEP484 mandates:

For a checked function, the default annotation for arguments and for the return type is Any

